# Jquery mobile - How to prevenet collapsible div from expanding after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Is there any way how to disable expand in collapsible div with jquery mobile ? I use jqm version 1.2.1. Thank you very much.

Default state, I need that state after I click on for example about_ats:

[image: menu_collapse]

State after click I don't want to show that space between after click:

[image: menu_expand]

HTML:

```
<div id="about_ats" data-role="collapsible">
     <h3>About ATS</h3>
     {*<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
           <li><a href="/{$country}/{$lang}/8_about-ats.html">About ATS</a></li>
     </ul>*}
</div>
```

Comment: when do you want to prevent it from expanding?

Comment: Hi Omar, I post picture for more info about my problem.

Comment: updated with pictures.

Comment: problem solved: `$('#about_ats h3 a').click(function(e){
      $('#about_ats').trigger('expand');
   });`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, is to `return false` once *collapsible heading* is clicked. All *collapsibles heading* have class `ui-collapsible-heading-toggle`, so you need to specify which one to prevent from *expanding* by specifying *collapsible*'s ID.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
  $("#about_ats .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").on("click", false);
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/zXhHz/)**